# Nautilus: Open folder in terminal when using tmux

Tags: shell, fedora, terminal, gnome, tmux

I'm using fedora 25 gnome edition, zsh shell. I can right click, open folder in terminal. I configured gnome terminal to start tmux when it gets opened.

Now if I open folder in terminal, the terminal would open the default user directory instead of the actual directory I'm in. How to fix it?

[image]

I need to either pass additional parameters to tmux in gnome-terminal, or to Nautilus.

If that works with another file manager please let me know, and I'll consider the possibility of switching, but if it can be done using Nautilus, it's better.

Comment: Not to detract form the good answer below, but for future reference Dolphin has that functionality built-in with three options. One is to open a terminal in the the current directory. Second is to right-click and open a terminal in the selected directory directory. Third, my choice, is to open a panel in Dolphin in the current directory. With the last option, directory changes in the file panel and in the terminal panel stay in sync. And, the directory changes made in the file panel don't add `cd` commands to the command history of the terminal. Don't know if it can use zsh shell over bash.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver the answer below present two ways, the second method isn't working and I don't like nested sessions. I might give dolphin a go if nothing else worked, thanks

Comment: It is a bug that has been reported. Relevant bug reports: [cwd should be respected for custom commands](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748293), [terminal-nautilus doesn't set the correct directory for custom commands](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=706927)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used Linux as my main driver in a while, but there used to be a program `nautilus-open-terminal` for doing this, not sure if it's supported on Fedora though. Also, though I don't know if it's possible to install it on non-Ubuntu/Debian systems Canonical's Unity DE has this functionality built in, you could probably replicate the method used there in Gnome.

EDIT: In light of your comment, you might add the lines to your `.profile` to always open tmux in the current working directory of gnome-terminal as a disowned process (i.e. `tmux ./; disown -r && killall gnome-terminal`) so that when you right click and open terminal in directory it opens a gnome-terminal, and immediately opens an independant tmux windows, passing the working directory recieved by nautilus as an argument.

UPDATE: Okay, I have found two methods. Now each of these have their own issues, but hopefully one of them will work well enough for you. These methods were tested on a Debian 8.7 installation using Bash as the shell and the program `nautilus-open-terminal` to launch a terminal window in the current Nautilus/Nemo directory.

Method 1.) Simply add `tmux` to the very end of your `.bashrc` file (or in your case `.zshrc`.). Now any terminal window you open will immediately open tmux as a process in the working directory.

The pro to this method is it is simple and only opens one window.

The major con to this method is it will always run as a nested process in the current shell, so if that's a problem you may want to use the other method instead.

Method 2.) Add the line `gnome-terminal -e tmux ./` (no quotes around the process name this time) to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file. This will open a new terminal window that contains tmux as the main process.

The pros for this method are that the tmux window will be a detached process, and will still open with the current working directory set to the Nautilus/Nemo window's directory.

The con is that while it opens a tmux dedicated window, `exit` cannot be added to the `.bashrc` file or it will kill the tmux window as well. With that said the gnome-terminal that is used to spawn the tmux window can still be closed manually by clicking the `x` on the window, or running `exit` directly in the gnome-terminal once tmux has opened.

While the second method is less convenient in that you have to manually close the excess terminal window; it will open a dedicated tmux window in the current directory when the `Open In Terminal` context menu option is clicked.

Comment: AFAIK `nautilus-open-terminal` is now `gnome-terminal-nautilus` and it's responsible for showing terminal in right click menu and I already have it. What I don't know how to do is how to pass the current directory to tmux from it

Comment: First of all, if you decide to edit your answer please notify me by writing a comment, stackexchange doesn't notify the OP whenever a user edits his answer, I found out that you did so by luck.

Comment: if you mean by `.profile`, the terminal profile. I tried that just now and the terminal stops working, it says `The child process exited normally with status 1.`

Comment: @Lynob try putting it in `.zshrc` instead, you may also try using `gnome-terminal -e "tmux ./"` in place of the previously suggested command (once again in the `.zshrc` file instead of `.profile`.).

Comment: Now, in `.zshrc`, `gnome-terminal -e "tmux ./"`  gives `The child process exited normally with status 1.` and `tmux ./; disown -r && killall gnome-terminal` gives `unknown command: ./
/home/user/.zshrc:disown:173: job not found: -r`

Comment: @Lynob Ok, I have updated the answer, and have tested my suggestions myself this time first, they are confirmed working on Debian 8.7 w/ Bash shell.

Comment: The first method worked as you said it would.. the second method went into an infinite loop and kept creating terminals. I don't mind using the second method if it doesn't create an infinite number of terminals.

Comment: @Lynob do you have any other custom parameters at the end of your `.zshrc` file? In either event try running the command `gnome-terminal -e tmux ./` directly in a gnome terminal window and let me know what happens, I will install ZSH on my Debian VM and test it myself with ZSH as well, it may be an incompatibility problem with another parameter you used, but the specific syntax of the command may also need to be modified to work properly with ZSH.

Comment: @Lynob Ok, I just tested it with zsh, here are the steps I took: Installed zsh via apt-get, ran zsh, chose to auto-populate `.zshrc`, changed login shell from bash to zsh using `chsh -s /bin/zsh`, logged out and back in, ran command `gnome-terminal -e tmux ./` directly in terminal, it worked without issue. I then added the command to the very end of the `.zshrc` file, exited the terminal, launched a new one, it worked fine. Finally I used `Open Terminal Here` + `.zshrc`, once again worked fine. Your issue is probably a result of something in your `.zshrc` conflicting with the command.

Answer (score 0):

I have added:

```
# Start tmux if tmux is not already running
pgrep tmux >/dev/null 2>&1 || exec tmux
```

at the end of my .bashrc and it looks to me that everything is working fine. When I start a gnome-terminal manually (for the first time), tmux starts. If I open other terminals, they won't have tmux (and this is pretty much what I want). And opening a terminal from any folder in Nautilus (with "Open in Terminal") also works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

With `TMUX` environment variable, we can use `exit` to automatically kill the original terminal when exiting the tmux session.

```bsh
if [[ "$TMUX" == "" ]]  # if not on tmux
then
    tmux
    exit
fi
```

It also prevents "`sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force`" message caused by calling `tmux` within a tmux session.