# "gnome-terminal -e tmux ./" keeps opening terminals forever

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, tmux, gnome-terminal

I recently asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346008/nautilus-open-folder-in-terminal-when-using-tmux). I won't ever use the first method.

`gnome-terminal -e tmux ./` if I put that in `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` (both shells, same problem). If I use that, the terminal will keep opening new terminals forever, infinite loop.

I asked the user about it, he said it's working on his computer, so I accepted his answer, he tried to help and the bounty was going to expire, but the issue is still there.

If I issue that command, it works great but not when it `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`. The user thinks my `.zshrc` is wrong, but it isn't, otherwise I'd have seen an error when sourcing. anyhow here it is

```
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
plugins=(git)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
alias ll='ls -l'
alias rm='rm -i'
alias ..="cd .."
alias ...="cd ../.."
alias ....="cd ../../.."
alias .....="cd ../../../.."
alias ......="cd ../../../../.."
alias githd='git reset --hard HEAD'
alias bre='gedit ~/.zshrc'
alias brs='source ~/.zshrc'
alias wl='sudo modprobe -r wl'
alias clam='sudo clamscan  -r -i / > ~/clamav/clamav.log'
alias xa='sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run'
alias net='sudo nethogs'
alias android='sudo sh /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh'
alias rmgit='sudo rm -rf .git'
# Functions
function conv () { if ffmpeg -i $1 -codec copy $2;
then gvfs-trash $1 && cd ..;
fi }
function rt() { gvfs-trash $@; }
function mkcd {
  last=$(eval "echo \$$#")
  if [ ! -n "$last" ]; then
    echo "Enter a directory name"
  elif [ -d $last ]; then
    echo "\`$last' already exists"
  else
    mkdir $@ && cd $last
  fi
}
function j { java -jar $1; }
cmd() { curl "http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/matching/$(echo "$@" \
    | sed 's/ /-/g')/$(echo -n $@ | base64)/plaintext" ;}
calc() {
  if which python2 &>/dev/null; then
    python2 -ic "from __future__ import division; from math import *; from random import *"
  elif which python3 &>/dev/null; then
    python3 -ic "from math import *; import cmath"
  elif which bc &>/dev/null; then
    bc -q -l
  else
    echo "Requires python2, python3 or bc for calculator features"
  fi
}
myip() {
  echo "--------------- Network Information ---------------"
  echo "router ip:" $(netstat -rn | awk 'FNR == 3 {print $2}')
  # newer system like archlinux
  ip addr | awk '/global/ {print $1,$2}' | cut -d\/ -f1
  ip addr | awk '/global/ {print $3,$4}'
  ip addr | awk '/ether/ {print $1,$2}'
  ip addr | awk '/scope link/ {print $1,$2}' | cut -d\/ -f1
  # older system like debian
  ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/ {print $1,$2}' | awk -F: '{print $1,$2}'
  ifconfig | awk '/Bcast/ {print $3}' | awk -F: '{print $1,$2}'
  ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/ {print $4}' | awk -F: '{print $1,$2}'
  ifconfig | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $4,$5}'
  ifconfig | awk '/Scope:Link/ {print $1,$3}' | cut -d\/ -f1
  # echo External IP $(curl -s http://checkip.dyndns.org/ | grep -o "[[:digit:].]\+")
  # echo External IP: $(curl -s http://ipaddr.io/)
  # echo External IP: $(curl -s https://icanhazip.com/)
  # echo External IP: $(curl -s https://ifconfig.co/)
  # echo External IP: $(curl -s http://pasteip.me/api/cli/ && echo)
  echo external ip: $(curl -s http://ipecho.net/plain)
  echo "---------------------------------------------------"
}
down4me() { curl -s "http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/$1" | sed '/just you/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g';}
# Needed for virtualenvwrapper
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.7
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Documents/Projects/Python
source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

**.tmux.conf**

```
assume-paste-time 1
base-index 0
bell-action any
bell-on-alert off
default-command ""
default-shell "/bin/zsh"
destroy-unattached off
detach-on-destroy on
display-panes-active-colour red
display-panes-colour blue
display-panes-time 1000
display-time 750
history-limit 2000
key-table "root"
lock-after-time 0
lock-command "lock -np"
message-command-style fg=yellow,bg=black
message-style fg=black,bg=yellow
mouse off
prefix C-b
prefix2 None
renumber-windows off
repeat-time 500
set-remain-on-exit off
set-titles off
set-titles-string "#S:#I:#W - "#T" #{session_alerts}"
status on
status-interval 15
status-justify left
status-keys emacs
status-left "[#S] "
status-left-length 10
status-left-style default
status-position bottom
status-right " "#{=21:pane_title}" %H:%M %d-%b-%y"
status-right-length 40
status-right-style default
status-style fg=black,bg=green
update-environment "DISPLAY SSH_ASKPASS SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_CONNECTION WINDOWID XAUTHORITY"
visual-activity off
visual-bell off
visual-silence off
word-separators " -_@"
```

running `HOME=/home/user/Documents gnome-terminal -e tmux ./` from terminal for example, won't work, it would open tmux but not in `Documents` folder but in `~/`

Comment: If it's in your shell's `rc` file, the behavior you are seeing makes sense.  GNOME-Terminal opens, runs tmux.  It starts your shell.  The shell parses the `rc` file, and sees a directive to run GNOME-Terminal.

Comment: @DopeGhoti what file? the one posted above? what's the problem with that so I can fix it, `zshrc` is posted in the question

Comment: I was referring to the command in your question you're having trouble with, `gnome-terminal -e tmux ./`.  What you probably want to do is look at GNOME-Terminal's settings and tell _it_ that you want it to run `tmux` in every new window you open.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I tried that, I thought so too. Putting `gnome-terminal -e tmux ./` in the terminal preferences settings won't work. and putting `tmux` there + `gnome-terminal -e tmux ./` in zsh gives the same problem

Comment: Post all applicable configuration files. In particular we need to see your tmux configuration. Copy the relevant files to another directory and run `HOME=/that/other/directory gnome-terminal -e tmux ./`. If you can't reproduce the problem then you missed a relevant file. Include all relevant files in your question.

Comment: @Gilles OK will do that tomorrow morning

Comment: @Gilles please read my edit

Comment: @DopeGhoti please read my edit